# Symfony dilemma: Generic entity, specific method

Tags: php, symfony

So I've got the following method in Behat's FeatureContext:

```
/**
 * @Given these :arg1 have the following Songs:
 * @throws ORMException
 */
public function theseHaveTheFollowingSongs($parentType, TableNode $table) {
    foreach ($table->getColumnsHash() as $row) {
        $song = new Song($row['title'], $row['length']);
        $this->em->persist($song);
        $parentEntity = $this->entities[$parentType][$row['id']];
        $parentEntity->setSong($song);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use the method setSong to a generic entity with the 
assumption that this generic entity in this particular case will always have the setSong method, and 'setX' in another method.

PHP doesn't seem to have a missingMethodException I can use.
So this causes git to complain when I want to make a commit:

`Warning:(170, 28) Method 'setSong' not found in`

And rightfully so.
But how to solve this dilemma without a missingMethodException to throw?

I tried BadMethodCallException, but that does not take away the warning.

Comment: You could try to ensure that parentEntity is the right type by using `instanceof`

Comment: So something like `if ($parentEntity instanceof SongParentInterface)`?

Comment: No wait, that wouldn't work, because it's not an interface, but an entitytype, which could all kinds of types. So I would `if ($parentEntity instanceof Album || $parentEntity instanceof MovieOST || $parentEntity instanceof GameOST || etc.)`